# Error while installing Elasticsearch on Windows

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have setup the Java path and I tried to run ElasticSearch on Windows 7. But I'm getting this error:

> "no java.exe found on C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\".

I can run `java` & `javac`, they work fine.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: is the " at the end of C:\Programe Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\" normal ?

Comment: Yes. JAVA_HOME points to an invalid Java installation (no java.exe found in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\"). Existing...

Answer (score 9):

So, I've kept hitting this problem and the solution is twofold. Like Udit said your Java_Home path should not include the bin folder (the reason being that the elastic search bat file seems to add on the bin folder manually, so if you add it the path would be bin\bin)

The second thing to check for is spaces in your path. If Java is installed to C:\Program Files then use C:\Progra~1 and if it's in C:\Program Files (x86) then use C:\Progra~2.

This should mean your Java_Home is set to something like C:\Progra~1\Java\jre7

To Verify this works open a command prompt and type %Java_Home%\bin\java and press return, you should then see all the command line parameters for Java listed. If you get this far you should be able to just run elasticsearch.bat

Answer (score 4):

**JAVA_HOME** is the environment variable that points to Java installation directory. 
Example: If u have installed Java in 32 bit windows 7 operating system, it would have installed in

> C:/Program Files/Java/jdkx.x.x

This path should be put as JAVA_HOME. Probably you have set the path till bin directory i.e. *C:/Program Files/Java/jdkx.x.x/bin*

that is why it cannot find the java.exe.